# How is the author's name given a different color?

Tags: post-meta, comments, author, comment-meta, wp-comment-query

Author's and visitors' names use the same color in comments.The point here is that the color of the author's name is different in the comments. For example, in visitor comments, name is red. But, the name of the site author should be gray. (Only in comments)

I know an ID needs to be added for the author's comments. However, I could not add this ID. Therefore, the style I gave in style.css does not work either.

I just tried this in css, but that didn't work.

```
.comment-list .bypostauthor .fn {color: gray;}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `.comment-list` but that's not the class, it's `.commentlist`. You may also need to target the anchor link inside that tag explicitly to override link colours

Comment: I guess I need to add ID to separate author comments. How can I do that?

Comment: WP already does that, it adds `bypostauthor` to comments the author makes, the mistake was that you added a `-` in your CSS selector where there shouldn't have been. The HTML class is `commentlist` not `comment-list`

Comment: Ah! Yes. I have never noticed this. The way I was looking was to add a class and then style it. This was quick and it worked.

Comment: Glad you got it styled! WP usually adds lots of helpful classes, especially on post and body elements

Comment: And open to improvement. I tried a thing or two on it.

Here is an example: (changes the background color of the post.)

 commentlist .children .bypostauthor > article p 

Thanks.